# How to avoid error in do_prepare_recipe_sysroot stage?

Tags: embedded, yocto, openembedded, ros2

I have an error build my custom recipe with meta-tegra-community and ros2-galactic as following:

> ERROR: xxx-xxxx-core-v0.1.3-unstable-r0 do_prepare_recipe_sysroot: The file /usr/lib/libyaml-cpp.so.0.6 is installed by both yaml-cpp-060 and yaml-cpp, aborting

This error would be because conflict installation of same header files of yaml.cpp during constructing recipe-sysroot for my custom recipe.

deepstream-6.2 recipe in the meta-tegra-community use yaml-cpp-060 and ros2 use yaml-cpp_0.6.2 at the same time.

tegra world and ros world is OK when they use their package in each work space. but, on my side, I have to use these two worlds on my custom recipe and it occur conflicting packages.

I tried to use BBMASK and change dependency in the deepstream-6.2 recipes to use yam-cpp_0.6.2, but, sub libraries of deepstream try to find yaml-cpp-060 complain not to find it and build is failed.

I hope to get a solution for my case. I think I would have to change ros use yaml-cpp-0606 instead of yaml-cpp_0.6.2 using ros. But, I am not familiar with ros.

Can you please give me correct way?

BR.
Mark

Comment: If the files are identical in the packages, just pick the one you like less than the other, and delete the file during the do_install step, using a bbappend.

Comment: Hi Skandigraun,
Recipe name is different each other and package name after build them is different. 
I am not sure it break dependency of each other world if I remove the same files in manual.
But, I will try it thanks.